# :hover won't trigger because bounding box is in the way

Tags: html, css, hover

**EDIT:**
This seems to only be a problem on Safari

**Edit 2:**
The newest Safari beta fixes this problem

Here is my problem:

I am trying to create a circular tab behind a circular image and change the opacity when you hover over the tab.

The problem is, because the bounding box on the circular image is square and the image is in front of the tab, the :hover element won't trigger.

I created a JSFiddle that demonstrates this problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/hgarrerereyn/a6L5j/

Here is the code in the JSFiddle:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div1 {
height:50px;
width:50px;
border-radius:50px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
z-index:-1;
}

#div2 {
height:200px;
width:200px;
border-radius:200px;
background:blue;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}

/* This next part doesnt work :(  */

#div1:hover {
opacity:0.5;
}
```

I am okay using jQuery if pure CSS won't cut it.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hover seems to work fine in Chrome28, FF19, IE9. What browser and version are you using?

Comment: This seems to be a WebKit bug, still present in Chrome 27 but already fixed in newer versions.

Comment: working in chrome on osx as well.

Comment: Ah, so it seems to work on pretty much everything except Safari

Comment: Have you tried using the `::before` and `::after` [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to accomplish this (assuming that you only have one or two tabs per circle) ? Just a suggestion, I wouldn't want to recommend anything that breaks compatibility with the working browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to change even when hovering over the circle in div2, try setting  pointer-events: none; on the overlapping div.

BTW: I'm running the safari beta and the hover is taking affect as expected.  So the other answer may be wait :)

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6L5j/5/)

```
#div2 {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  border-radius:200px;
  background:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```